# Theming in tiling window managers?

Tags: gui, window-manager, tiling-wm, theme

I am trying out tiling window managers like scrotWM, and have noticed that GUI programs start with a "theme" (or lack, thereof) that looks like the bland Redmond theme. Is there a way to specify the appearance/themes of windows in a tiling window manager? Or is it window manager OR GUI toolkit specific? Is there anything I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, theming is specific to each particular application (window manager or otherwise). Applications that use the same GUI toolkit usually use the same configuration mechanism to select a theme, so they'll look the same.

Many tiling window managers are designed to have a low visible footprint, so there's not much room for visual theming. Maybe that's why you consider them bland.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but is there anything I can do to change the visual appearance?

Comment: @penyuan: You need to check the documentation of each window manager. For example, with [scrotwm](http://www.scrotwm.org/man.html), put `color_focus` settings and so on in your `~/.scrotwm.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

For GTK applications themes can be set in the file `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. Mine is

```
gtk-icon-theme-name="gnome"
```

and that makes various applications use the gnome icons. You can see a list of available icon themes in `/usr/share/icons/`.