# Theme config files for programs of common GUI toolkits

Tags: gui, tiling-wm, window, theme

As a follow up to my previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/theming-in-tiling-window-managers), I learned that theming in windows (when using a tiling window manager) could be achieved by modifying config files for the different GUI toolkits, for instance GTK is ~/.gtkrc-2.0

What are the config files for others like GNOME, KDE, QT, and others? And how do I set them up? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [gtk-chtheme](http://plasmasturm.org/code//gtk-chtheme/) to set the GTK2 options, and `qt-config` (part of Qt) to set Qt options. KDE will use the Qt theme if you havn't set anything else, but you should be able to run `kcontrol` and set a theme/fonts etc, if you want.

GNOME saves its configuration in their little registry. KDE saves in the Qt .ini format, under ~/.kde/ somewhere - can't remember or dig it up at the moment.
The GNOME and KDE enviroments rely on daemons running in the background. You can start the GNOME/KDE services yourself at login time, or just let them start when an application needs them. `gnome-settings-daemon` is the GNOME one, I'm not sure if you need to start any KDE daemons except having dbus available.